# Как реализовать исключения (try, except)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начал изучать python и хочу реализовать последовательность Коллатца.
Вот сам код:

```
    def collatz (number):
        global st
        st=0
        while number!=1:
            if number%2==0:
                number=number//2
                print(number)
                st=st+1
            elif number%2==1:
                number=3*number+1
                print(number)
                st=st+1
            continue
        print ("Мы получили единичку за", st, "шагов!")

s1 = int(input("Введите целое число: "))
collatz(s1)
```

В этом варианте все работает. Хочу добавить проверку если пользователь ввел букву вместо цифры. Получился вот такой код:

```
def collatz (number):
    global st
    st=0
    while number!=1:
        if number%2==0:
            number=number//2
            print(number)
            st=st+1
        elif number%2==1:
            number=3*number+1
            print(number)
            st=st+1
        continue
    print ("Мы получили единичку за", st, "шагов!")

try:
    s1 = int(input("Введите целое число: "))
except:
    print("Нужно ввести число!")
collatz(s1)
```

И вот такой ответ я вижу в IDE:

```
Введите целое число: q
Traceback (most recent call last):
Нужно ввести число!
  File "C:/Users/User/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/2.py", line 22, in <module>
    collatz(s1)
NameError: name 's1' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Я хочу чтобы программа выдавала пользователю сообщение "Нужно ввести число!" пока он не введет число и функция не отработает корректно.

Пробовал и так и сяк, не пойму почему не идет. Что я делаю не так и куда смотреть и что нужно исправить?
З.Ы. Хочется решить именно с использованием исключений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переместите вызов метода collatz(s1) в блок try, так как у вас s1 при появлении ошибки не инициализирована, вы ее обработали и далее пытаетесь вызвать.

```
def collatz (number):
        global st
        st=0
        while number!=1:
            if number%2==0:
                number=number//2
                print(number)
                st=st+1
            elif number%2==1:
                number=3*number+1
                print(number)
                st=st+1
            continue
        print ("Мы получили единичку за", st, "шагов!")

try:
    s1 = int(input("Введите целое число: "))
    collatz(s1)

except:
    print("Нужно ввести число!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Эту задачу можно реализовать без применения исключений. Например, с помощью цикла:

```
s1 = input("Введите целое число: ")

while s1.isdigit() == False:
    s1 = input("Введённое значение не является числом. Введите целое число: ")
```

В данном случае пользователь сможет повторить свою попытку без необходимости запускать сценарий вновь. Ваш код выдавал ошибку по той причине, что после обработки исключений продолжилось выполнение программы, вследствие чего переменная s1 не объявилась.

Answer (score 0):

```
def collatz (number):
    #...

while True:
    s1 = input('Введите целое число: ')
    if not s1.isdecimal():
        print('Нужно ввести число!')
    else:
        break

collatz(int(s1))
```

Answer (score -1):

А вот так можно с помощью рекурсии и исключений сделать тоже самое:

```
def get_user_input():
    try:
        return int(input("Введите целое число: "))
    except:
        print("Нужно ввести число!")
        return get_user_input()

s1 = get_user_input()
```

Это очень близко по смыслу к циклу while, но занимает больше строк кода.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не надо пытаться использовать рекурсию всюду только потому, что вы знаете, что это такое. Это хуже по производительности, а на большом числе повторов и вовсе может привести к падению программы.